# Can you set a byte-limit for Asio's read_until?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am using `boost::asio::read_until` to read from a socket until `"<EOF>"` is received. However, someone could send billions and billions of bytes until the system runs out of RAM and has to shut down.

To avoid that, I want to set a limit to `read_until`. Like "read until `"<EOF>"` or until 10MB are reached".

Is there an easy solution to that using `read_until`, or do I have to switch to `read` and manually end the reading when `"<EOF>"` is received?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@sehe has an excellent answer that allows to stop on EOF or when a specific number of bytes have been read. My versions are slightly and much more complicated but additionally allow to stop on any delimiter.

---

You could [construct](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_streambuf/basic_streambuf.html) your boost::asio::streambuf with a max size argument:

> The constructor for basic_streambuf accepts a size_t argument specifying the maximum of the sum of the sizes of the input sequence and output sequence. During the lifetime of the basic_streambuf object, the following invariant holds:
>
> `size() <= max_size()`
>
> Any member function that would, if successful, cause the invariant to be violated shall throw an exception of class std::length_error.

Or you could use this overload:

```
template<
    typename SyncReadStream,
    typename Allocator,
    typename MatchCondition>
std::size_t read_until(
    SyncReadStream & s,
    boost::asio::basic_streambuf< Allocator > & b,
    MatchCondition match_condition,
    boost::system::error_code & ec,
    typename enable_if< is_match_condition< MatchCondition >::value >::type *  = 0);
```

where the match condition function looks somewhat like this:

```
using iterator = buffers_iterator<basic_streambuf<Allocator>::const_buffers_type>;
/**
\brief Make read_until stop when either: 
    * the stop character was found
    * more than 100MB have been read
*/
pair<iterator, bool> match_condition(iterator begin, iterator end) {
   // to much data?
   if(end - begin > 100*1024*1024) {
      return std::make_pair(begin, true);
   }
   // try and find stop character
   for(auto i = begin; i < end; i++) {
      auto c = i.rdbuf()->sgetc();
      if(c == STOP_CHARACTER) {
         return std::make_pair(i, true);
      } 
   }

   return std::make_pair(begin, false);
}
```

(Making this work with a multi-character delimiter is left as an exercise for the reader)

Comment: This is nice but really overcomplicated, IYAM (see my answer)

Comment: @sehe you're right, I edited it a bit. I used it to check for "\r\n" so I thought the OP meant the actual letters '<', 'E', 'O', 'F', '>' and wrote my answer with that in mind

Comment: Actually, that's a valid way to read the question. No worries, in that case this is the best answer. +1

Comment: Mmm. Isn't [this simple `readuntil(s, sb, "<EOF>", ec)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e78c4f2d499b9a6) strictly better?

Comment: @sehe I'm not sure what you're asking. That is basically the normal invocation -- it is missing the size limitation. If you change it to be `streambuf sb(100);` it's what I had in mind with my first method

Comment: Hehe. Silly me. I forgot about the question for a moment :)

Answer (score 7):

Just use `transfer_exactly` which will *also* stop at EOF or buffer full:

```
auto transferred = read(s, sb, transfer_exactly(10u<<20), ec);
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a876617c68d56cb)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace ip;

int main() {
    boost::system::error_code ec;

    io_service svc;
    tcp::socket s(svc);
    s.connect(tcp::endpoint(address_v4::loopback(), 6767));

    streambuf sb;
    auto transferred = read(s, sb, transfer_exactly(10u<<20), ec);

    std::cerr << "read " << transferred << " till " << ec.message() << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im setting same limit using **streambuf** limiting. Example code(using coroutines):

```
try {
     boost::asio::streambuf req_buf(100 * 1024); //Limit memory for headers
     boost::asio::async_read_until(*sock, req_buf, "\r\n\r\n", yield);
}catch(boost::system::system_error &e) {
    if( e.code() == boost::asio::error::make_error_code(boost::asio::error::misc_errors::not_found) )
        log("HTTP Connection close: cannot find headers end");
     //..
}
```

Thats it. You can check error code in read callback and get specific error when searching element was not found in read buffer.